# vim tab completion for directories

Tags: vim, vi

In vim using a command that expects a file I can use tab to cycle through the files in a directory.

If it is currently showing a directory in the "cycle", is there a way to make it so that the next time I tab it will instead cycle through the currently shown directory? What I am currently doing is just pressing space and then backspace but is there a better way to do this?

For example, if I type

```
:e ~
```

then when I press tab I will cycle through the directories in my home directory, e.g. several presses of tab may give me

```
:e ~/Desktop/
:e ~/Documents/
:e ~/Downloads/
```

Now for example I may actually want to open a file in ~/Documents, so I'm wondering if there's a way to make it start cycling from ~/Documents/ instead of ~/

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply hit <kbd>Down</kbd> or <kbd>/</kbd> when you've reached `~/Documents`.
Note that using `/` will result in `~/Documents//`, but completion will still work (i.e show items in `~/Documents`).

**Edit**
You can also use <kbd>Ctrl - E</kbd>, which doesn't add the trailing `/` (and might be easier to type)

Comment: YES!!! Thank you! I don't really like <down> since it's so far from the main keys but "/" is great! Never would have thought it would work though since ~/Documents actually is ~/Documents/ so pressing "/" gives ~/Documents// but it does!